# c programming query regarding assignment operator Please specifythe output with reason in windows and linux

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
   int x=-1, y=-1;
   if(++x=++y)
     printf("pppppppp");
   else
    printf("cccccccc");
}
```

Comment: Somebody needs to write a quick script to disallow questions with the string "Please specify the output with reason in windows and linux." If I can't post an answer with a link to lmgtfy then it can't be that hard.

Answer (score 2):

In `C` your code won't compile [you cannot assign to `rvalues`]

In `C++` `if(++x=++y)` invokes Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: but wecant assign constant to a constant so it shouldgiveerror

Comment: how doesthiscodegetcompiled& givesoutput pppppppppp

Comment: @User : Are you compiling your code as a `*.cpp` file? In C assignment to `++x` is not valid.

Comment: C++ was not tagged, so you can omit C++. The code just dont pass the C compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning -1 to x and y. In the comparison, you are incrementing both variables before evaluation, so both x and y are 0. This means x=0. So x is assigned 0 and this is the result of the evaluation. Because this is regarded as false in logic operations, "ccccccccccc" is printed to the screen.

Please note that people don't usually put an assignment into an if/while/ect... and when you see this in code, it is usually an error. The comparison operator is ==.

Comment: so what isthecorrect output will it givean error or it will print

Answer (score 0):

The code tries to assign a value to something that's not a lvalue.

Pass the code eaxample to a compiler before posting.

Comment: this prints but actually it shouldnot because howcan weassign a contant to anotherconstant

Comment: @user448302: So why asked you the question?